# I want two arrays with one foreach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to run both `dogsbread` and `dogsname` array from the same `for each`. Can I do that, and if not then how to print both of the `foreach`’s outputs at the same line?

[image]

```
<% dogsbread.forEach(function(dogsbread){ %>
    <h1><%= dogsbread %></h1>
<%});%>
<% dogsname.forEach(function(dogsname){ %>
    <h1><%= dogsname %></h1>
<%});%>
```

Comment: Are you using ERB?, how are your arrays?

Comment: Try this at console. dogsbread.forEach(function(item, index) {console.log(item + dogsname[index])});

Comment: I hope this will give you access to both arrays dogsbread and dogsname. Let me know if it works